# About the probability mass function in permutation

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $a$ be a random permutation in $S_{10}$. For the
random variable $$X(a) = |a_1 - a_2 |+|a_3 - a_4 |+|a_5 - a_6 |+|a_7 - a_8 |+|a_9 - a_{10} |$$

find probability mass function $p_X(x)$.

---

I found that domain was $2x+5 \ \ \ (x=0,1,2,  \cdots  ,  10 )$
but difficult to assign probabilities.

For example,

$(1 \ 2) (3\  4) (5\  6) (7\  8) (9 \ 10)$

$p_X (5) =  \frac   {5! \times 2^5} {10!}  $

$(1 \ 3) (2\  4) (5\  6) (7\  8) (9 \ 10)$

$p_X ( 7) =   \frac {5! \times 2^5 \times 4 } {10!} $  (4 is select neighbor)

...

$p_X ( 2k+5 ) =  ? $

I think some combinatory identity or mathmatical induction gives good results.